# How to plot function sin(x)^2 / x^2

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

The above function looks like this:

[image]

However, using tikzpicture with addplot

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-6:6,samples=50,smooth,red] { (sin(x)^2)/pow(x,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives the following disturbing result:

[image]

How should I plot `sin(x)^2 / x^2` in tikz?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then they will not have to guess 80% of your setup.

Comment: Try more samples and `sin(deg(x))`

Comment: Yes, it seems sin(deg(x)) is required when plotting sin(x). Thanks!

Comment: @daleif Damn! I did not see your comment :) Also sampling is just as fine, as it is now. Only `deg(...)` is necessary with `sin`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `sin(x)^2` with `pow(sin(x),2)`, or even writing the whole function as `pow(sin(x)/x,2)`?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help

Comment: As noticed by @daleif, default angle units in `pgfplots` are degrees. You are plotting really near zero (which you must avoid, for being the function not defined there) and you have huge rounding errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commented by @daleif, the problem is that the trigonometric functions in pgfplots are defined with the argument in degrees, not in radians. So you are calculating the function really near zero, and you have huge rounding errors (and wrong scale...).

You can use `sin(deg(x))` to do the conversion, or globally switch with `\pgfplotsset{trig format=rad}`.

Notice however that the manual states:

> /pgf/trig format=deg|red [sic, should be rad]
>
> Allows to reconfigure
>   the trigonometric format for all user arguments. This affects all user
>   arguments including view, Tik Z polar coordinates, pins of \nodes,
>   start/end angles for edges, etc. At the time of this writing, this
>   feature is in experimental state: it can happen that it breaks Tik Z
>   internals. Please handle with care and report any bugs.

In this case it works:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{trig format=rad}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-6:6,samples=50,smooth,red] { (sin(x)^2)/pow(x,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that you have to avoid the point `x=0` in your drawing, where the function is undefined... this is with:

```
\addplot[domain=-6:6,samples=151,smooth,red] { (sin(x)^2)/pow(x,2) };
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution for comparison purpose only.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f{(sin(x)/x)^2}
\psset
{
    yunit=4cm,
    xunit=.5cm  
}   

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,plotpoints=200](-12,-.1)(12.5,1.2)
    \psaxes[Dx=5]{->}(0,0)(-12,-.1)(12,1.1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-12}{12}{\f}
    \uput[45](*.7 {\f}){$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is with `pgfplots`, and it can be solved by switching to `gnuplot`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [domain=-6:6, samples=50] {sin(x)**2/x**2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nope, works just fine for me without gnuplot.